# Перенос строк CSS PHP

Tags: php, html, css, перенос

джентльмены!
Возникла такая ситуация.
Есть блок с текстом, текст выводится пользовательский.
Сейчас, если в тексте есть пробелы, то если текст не умещается в блок, то он переносится на месте пробела и текст выглядит красиво, слова не разбиваются по буквам. Проблема в том, что если пользователь введёт строку без пробелов, то такая строчка не переносится и выходит за блок.
Оба эти варианта решаются word-break, но он решает одну проблему и создаёт проблему другим случаем.

Вопрос: можно ли сделать на CSS/HTML или PHP так, что если в тексте есть пробелы, то он будет разбиваться там, а если в тексте нет пробелов, то текст будет переносится автоматически, если он не умещается.
Ну и ситуация, если в тексте 1000 символов и 1 пробел, то текст не должен делится на 2 части и в итоге уезжать за его приделы.
Как можно сделать такой перенос, чтобы исправить оба случая?

Заранее, большое спасибо!

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` пробовали?

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов.

```css
    .div {
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        background-color: #003eff;
        color: white;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: keep-all;
        line-break: normal;
        -webkit-hyphens: none;
        width: 150px;
        border: 4px double black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="div">fosdhfohsdoighodhgpsdhgpahdgokshdogkjhsdkjhgksjdhgjkshdglkjhsdljkghsdlkjhglkjsdhglkjhsdlgkjhsdljkhglksjdhglkjsdhglkjhsdlkjhg</div>
<div class="div">Совесть человечества спит, и не стоит рассчитывать, что она когда-нибудь проснется сама по себе. Это так же невозможно, как попытка вытащить самого себя из болота за волосы. Нужна помощь извне</div>
<div class="div">— Теория — этоосновапрактики.Развеисследованиефундаментальныхзаконовприроды непринесетобществусамуюбольшуюпрактическуюпользу?</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос уже решён. Если можете, пожалуйста, удалите ответ, чтобы я мог удалить вопрос. Протупил чутка, неловко теперь. Спасибо за понимание